# Three Columns Content First

Tags: html, layout

Here's revisiting an old problem. How do I develop a three-column layout where the main content is in the middle with sidebars on either side, but the main content is first in the HTML markup?

```
<body>
  <section id="main">
    <h1>Main Section Title</h1>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" />
    <p>This is the main content most important to readers</p>
  </section>
  <aside id="highlights"><!-- left column -->
    <h2>Highlights</h2>
    news feed goes here...
  </aside><!-- end left column -->
  <aside id="participate"><!-- right column -->
    <h2>social Network</h2>
    social media links here...
    <h2>Events</h2>
    events listing here...
  </aside><!-- end right column -->
</body>
```

Comment: Related observation: I came across ARIA-ROLE information, which addresses the accessibility issues at http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#document_structure_roles

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions:

1) edit: deleted

2) use absolute positioning, this isn't very responsive, but you can put things exactly where you want, what DreamWeaver used to do

3) Use Javascript to rearrange the sections and asides. Move the left one to be first, but that's probably not what you want on narrow screens

4) What they suggest in AListApart:http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail/

Comment: seems like option 1 won't work because the asides appear after the main section in the markup

Comment: I just edited that answer and added a post from AListApart that discusses this exact problem